# polling-xhr.js:157 Error 502 Bad Gateway While trying to establish connection between the client and the server using SocketIO

Tags: nginx, flask, ssl, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to deploy a simple flask application where client and server can communicate with each other using SocketIO. Below code is working fine without any errors locally, but it's throwing errors while deploying.
These are the only files I'm using,

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret"
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on("message")
def handleMessage(data):
    print("Message : " + data["data"]);
    data["data"] = "Hello"
    send(data)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

**home.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sockets</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + "//" + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

                socket.on("connect", function() {
                    socket.send({data : "Connected"});
                });

                socket.on("message", function(data) {
                    console.log(data.data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to deploy this on **AWS ec2**, I've used **nginx** web server and **gunicorn3** as wsgi. I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Gc8CMjQZfc&list=PL5KTLzN85O4KTCYzsWZPTP0BfRj6I_yUP) to deploy this application.

**Versions**

```
nginx - 1.14.0.
gunicorn3 - 19.7.1.
flask - 2.0.3.
flask_socketio - 5.1.1.
```

**nginx configuration**

```
server{
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/sockets-bundle/domain.cert.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /home/ubuntu/sockets-bundle/intermediate.cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/sockets-bundle/private.key.pem;

        server_name emoviz.biz;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        location /static {
                alias /home/ubuntu/flaskapp/static;
                expires 30d;
        }

        location /socket.io {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
        }
}
```

I've tried many solutions provided on Stackoverflow and Github related to this but couldn't make it work. I'm new to deployment, I don't know what exactly causing the below error I've tried cors, downgrading things but couldn't find a solution. Any help to make it work would be much appreciated.

**Error**
[image: Error log]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch on your proxied ports. For the HTTP side you seem to be using port 5000:

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
```

But then for your Socket.IO route you put port 5000 instead:

```
    location /socket.io {
            // ...
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
```

Based on the 502 errors that you are getting, my guess is that the correct port is 8000, so you should change the 5000 to 8000.